# Can't open Microsoft Speech Recognition API via Post with Delphi

Tags: delphi, ssl, https, speech, indy10

I want to send a Post request to  Microsoft Speech Recognition API via HTTPS using Indy's TIdHTTP in Delphi.

On Microsofts Speech Recognition API Page: [Microsoft Speech Recognition API Get started with speech recognition by using the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/cognitive-services/speech/getstarted/getstartedrest?tabs=Powershell#tabpanel_AFC9x30-dR_Powershell)

they write you should send a HTTP POST Request like this:

```
POST     https://speech.platform.bing.com/speech/recognition/interactive/cognitiveservices/v1?language=en-US&format=detailed HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json;text/xml
Content-Type: audio/wav; codec=audio/pcm; samplerate=16000
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY
Host: speech.platform.bing.com
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Expect: 100-continue
```

I try this with Delphi XE 10 Indy.

But I ever got Error 400 - Bad Request as Answer!

What do I false in the following code?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Response, csrf, url: String;
  PostStream: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;

  HTTPClient: TIdHTTP;
  SSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;


begin
  url := 'https://speech.platform.bing.com/speech/recognition/interactive/cognitiveservices/v1?language=en-US&format=detailed HTTP/1.1';

  HTTPClient := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    HTTPClient.Disconnect;
    HTTPClient.AllowCookies := True;
    SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(HTTPClient);
    SSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
    HTTPClient.IOHandler := SSL;
    HTTPClient.HandleRedirects := true;

    HTTPClient.Request.Accept := 'application/json;text/xml';
    HTTPClient.Request.Method := 'POST';
    HTTPClient.Request.ContentType := 'audio/wav; codec=audio/pcm;   samplerate=16000';

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------


    PostStream := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
    try
      PostStream.AddFormField('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key','YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY');

      PostStream.AddFile('file', 'test.wav');


      Response := HTTPClient.Post(url, PostStream);

      PostStream.Clear;


    finally
     PostStream.Free;
    end;

  finally
    HTTPClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Do some debugging. What was transmitted by your code?

Comment: @David: What do I false in the code?

Comment: Do some debugging. What does your post request look like.

Comment: This is not the right answer for my question. Debug by self if you can.

Comment: Did you post your subscription key or YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY?

Comment: No. I'm helping you learn how to debug. Check what you actually post. That's the starting point of your debugging. This site doesn't exist to do your job for you.

Comment: @Sertac:  Of course YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY send

Comment: @David you don't need to help in debug. I think the problem is i can't set -> Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Comment: Never mind. Do it your way.

Comment: @david: your answer was just a standard answer, which also fits to 1000 other questions. Only quantity, no quality

Comment: It's fine. If you don't want to learn to debug, I'm no longer interested.

Comment: @David: You won't understand. This is not a Debugging Problem. This is a Problem with Delphi and INDY. With CURL it works fine

Comment: @David: And  I know, Remy Lebeau can help me. Not such basics like you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166166/discussion-between-ingo-and-david-heffernan).

Comment: @Ingo Debugging includes making sure your code fits the documented process

Comment: If you'd looked at the actual post request, you'd have seen that it doesn't match the spec. Which is precisely what Remy told you. Of course he did your work for you, gave you the code, and now you have working code but you've learnt nothing. You still don't know how to debug. Which means the next time you get stuck you'll come back here asking for somebody else to write your code. If you learnt to debug you'd be able to solve your own problems.

Comment: @David: Why you don't told my that: -> TIdHTTP even has an overload of Post() specifically for uploading just a file. I never figured this out with debugging. I wrote in my Question that the answer from the MS Server was 'HTTP Error 400 BAD Request'

Comment: Forget it. Have it your way.

Comment: @David: Yes and you debug your asm code again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `POST` request is not setup the way Microsoft's documentation says. Most importantly, you should not be using `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` at all, since the REST server is not expecting a request in `multipart/form-data` format. The body of the request is expected to be *just* the actual WAV file and nothing else.  `TIdHTTP` even has an overload of `Post()` specifically for uploading just a file.

Try this instead:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Response, url: String;
  HTTPClient: TIdHTTP;
  SSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  url := 'https://speech.platform.bing.com/speech/recognition/interactive/cognitiveservices/v1?language=en-US&format=detailed';

  HTTPClient := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(HTTPClient);
    SSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
    HTTPClient.IOHandler := SSL;

    HTTPClient.AllowCookies := True;
    HTTPClient.HandleRedirects := true;

    HTTPClient.Request.Accept := 'application/json;text/xml';
    HTTPClient.Request.ContentType := 'audio/wav; codec=audio/pcm; samplerate=16000';
    HTTPClient.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'] := 'YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY';

    Response := HTTPClient.Post(url, 'test.wav');
  finally
    HTTPClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Hello Remy, you are the best. Yes this code works fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Ingo:  Then why haven't you accepted Remy's answer?